# PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading: a

Tags: logging, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Error that I'm getting on databricks:

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     71                 file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback
     72             )
---> 73             cp.dump(obj)
     74             return file.getvalue()
     75 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in dump(self, obj)
    600     def dump(self, obj):
    601         try:
--> 602             return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    603         except RuntimeError as e:
    604             if "recursion" in e.args[0]:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in _file_reduce(obj)
    314         )
    315     if "r" not in obj.mode and "+" not in obj.mode:
--> 316         raise pickle.PicklingError(
    317             "Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading: %s"
    318             % obj.mode

PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading: a
```

Backstory- Trying to log the print statements in a file, but when it goes into an UDF functions, throws up the above error. Anyone has any idea what might be going wrong?

Works well in some pandas UDF functions, but doesn't in some.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot log to same file from a parallel operation possibly running on multiple cores on same machine. For logging in spark, use the spark logger instead:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

def log_info(info: str):
  spark = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
  log4jLogger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j
  logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger("joblog")
  logger.info(info)
```

Comment: This looks perfect for my case. Can you please add on how can I implement this to log all my print() statement outputs in a text file?

Comment: Spark is a distrbuted system . Technically you can write to a text file. But you have to make sure, that each worker writes to its own file. 

Spark build in logging does this for you. The log files are then collected from each worker and can be viewed in Spark UI

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html#executors-tab

Comment: a common way of debugging spark btw is also , just do the data transformation you anticipate on dataframe or rdd. Then inspect if the result is correct with 
df.head or df.first etc